# Pass variable from one page to another, then discard it

Tags: php

Is there a way I can pass a variable from one page to another but it only work on the next page clicked? After that it can be discarded/destroyed.

I've tried a php session but can't seem to kill the session on the next page clicked... or even if that way may be the wrong way to approach it.

Here's my session code:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $x = $category;
  $_SESSION['sessionVar'] = $x;
  echo "$x";
?>


<?php
  session_start();
  $x = $_SESSION['sessionVar'];
  echo "$x";
?>
```

I want to do this without having to submit a form.

Comment: `<a href="foo.php?var=value">click</a>`?

Comment: You failed to `unset($_SESSION['sessionVar'])` in your second snippet.

Comment: @MarcB Didn't know it was that simple, how would I then access that variable on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a variable via a php session and then unset the variable on the following page.

```
$_SESSION['my_var'] = "some data";
```

`$_SESSION['my_var'] = null;
unset($_SESSION['my_var']);`

Answer (score 0):

Send it as POST:

```
<form action="nextpage.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="yourvariable" value="12345" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next page" />
</form>
```

Is it what was supposed?